# Datetimepicker selected date to print in a new format with spaces

Tags: c#, printing

My printing paper contains a place to print the date in eight boxes which is like the image attached and first two characters of the year is already printed [image: date should be printed within this boxes]

I am using c# datetimepicker and date format is set to custom format. While i am printing the selected value it shows like this 7/24/2015. I need to remove the "/" marks and only the characters should be printed in the boxes. each box height is 0.6 cm width is also same. I need to setup the printing correctly and if a date is like "e.g : 9" then it should be printed like "0 9". How can i do this in c# printing. Following is my code part

string theDate1 = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("ddMM  yy");
g.DrawString("" + theDate1 + "  .", new Font("Arial", 19, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Brown, new PointF(510, 68));

Comment: The printing format is its own question, but you can format a date into the string you need like this: `MyDate.ToString("ddMMyyyy")` or `MyDate.ToString("ddMM  yy")` if the century is populated already on the form.

Comment: @StevenEccles I am using a code like this but its not working string theDate1 = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("ddmm yy"); g.DrawString("" + theDate1, new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Brown, new PointF(510, 68));
But its not working

Comment: @LarsTech thanks its printing the month correct. I have to print the date in two boxes. In the same way month and year. i need to add two character space between date, month and year e.g( 0  9  0  7       15) like this. how can i change this coding part to add space

Comment: With output like that, I would parse the string and print each individual number inside the rectangle box.

Comment: @LarsTech Can you please help me with a sample line of code or a link that i can find a way

Comment: You would have to post your printing code into your question.